# How to add an attribute to any level of objects (list, list\$frame, list\$frame\$column)?

Tags: r

My problem is as follows: I'm trying to write a function that sets a collection of attributes on an object in a given environment. I'm trying to mimic a metadata layer, like SAS does, so you can set various attributes on a variable, like label, decimal places, date format, and many others.

Example:

```
SetAttributes(object = "list$dataframe$column", label="A label", width=20, decDigits=2, 
              dateTimeFormat="....", env=environment())
```

But I have to set attributes on different levels of objects, say:

```
comment(list$dataframe$column) <- "comment on a column of a dataframe in a list"
comment(dataframe$column) <- "comment on a column of a dataframe"
comment(list) <- "comment on a list/dataframe/vector"
```

Alternatively it can be done like this:

```
comment("env[[list]][[dataframe]][[column]]) <- "text" 
# (my function recognizes both formats, as a variable and as a string with chain of 
# [[]] components).
```

So I have implemented it this way:

```
SetAttributes <- function(varDescription, label="", .........., env=.GlobalEnv) {
parts <- strsplit( varDescription, "$", fixed=TRUE)[[1]]
if(length(parts) == 3) {
          lst <- parts[1]
          df <- parts[2]
          col <- parts[3]

          if(!is.na(label))        comment(env[[lst]][[df]][[col]]) <- label
          if(!is.na(textWidth))    attr(env[[lst]][[df]][[col]], "width") <- textWidth
....
} else if(length(parts) == 2) {
df <- varTxtComponents[1]
col <- varTxtComponents[2]

if(!is.na(label))        comment(env[[df]][[col]])         <- label
if(!is.na(textWidth))    attr(env[[df]][[col]], "width")   <- textWidth
....
} else if(length(parts) == 1) {
....
```

You see the problem now: I have three blocks of similar code for length(parts) == 3, 2 and 1

When I tried to automatize it this way:

```
path <- c()
sapply(parts, FUN=function(comp){ path <<- paste0(path, "[[", comp, "]]") )}
comment(eval(parse(text=paste0(".GlobalEnv", path)))) <- "a comment"
```

I've got an error:

```
Error in comment(eval(parse(text = paste0(".GlobalEnv", path)))) <- "a comment" : 
target of assignment expands to non-language object
```

Is there any way to get an object on any level and set attributes for it not having a lot of repeated code?

PS: yes, I heard thousand times that changing external variables from inside a function is an evil, so please don't mention it. I know what I want to achieve.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just to make sure you hear it 1001 times, it's a very bad idea for a function to have side effects like this. This is a very un R-like way to program something like this. If you're going to write R code, it's better to do things the R way. This means returning modified objects that can optionally be reassigned. This would make life much easier.

Here's a simplified version which only focuses on the comment.

```
SetComment <- function(varDescription, label=NULL, env=.GlobalEnv) {
    obj <- parse(text= varDescription)[[1]]
    eval(substitute(comment(X)<-Y, list(X=obj, Y=label)), env)
}

a<-list(b=4)
comment(a$b)
# NULL 
SetComment("a$b", "check")
comment(a$b)
# [1] "check"
```

Here, rather than parsing and splitting the string, we build an expression that we evaluate in the proper context. We use `substitute()` to pop in the values you want to the actual call.

Comment: Just to be clear and not leaving it without explanation - such objects I'm commenting have hundreds of MB and I have a lot of them. When trying follow the R style (passing by value), R session crashes constantly. Every other language can pass objects by references, but not R. I won't make a risk of crash again and again and copying some GB of data just for adding some attributes to data frame. Unfortunately, R doesn't have a metadata layer and I have to implement my own - or stick with expensive SAS. So modifying objects from a function is really my least problem :)

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot vote up as I have too small reputation. Your solution is general, I tested it with very complex set of objects and it works perfect. I've learnt very useful thing.

Comment: @Bastian, what version of R do you have?